# IIS doesn't show 403 error

Tags: wordpress, iis

I have installed wordpress at iis and recently I've added ipsecurity for login page. Looks like it's working but I get blank page instead of 403 error page when access denied. Please look a screenshot attached. http://joxi.ru/QIc9VIwyTJBWeXfMnZo

Any ideas?

Thanks, Oleg

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution removing the following line from web.config

`<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />`